# Control complex flow nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to use a library like async to control flow in NodeJS. I checked async, it has series, parallel, waterfall, they are not suitable. Waterfall seems well but not enough. My code is like:

```
checkInMemcache(resultl, function(
 {
   if(!result) {
     checkInMongo(result2, function(
      {
        if(result2) {
         checkOther(result3, function() {
           if else ..
         })
        } else {
         .. do something
        }
      }
     ) 
   } else {
     .. do something
   }
 }
)
```

Comment: How about promises like [q](https://npmjs.org/package/q)

Comment: It's not easy to implement :( and look like original code ..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on those nice control flow patterns. Grasping them will allow you to go without any libs in the beginning for simple concurrency / async problems:

Check this one out: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html

Another good read worth checking is:

http://trevorburnham.com/presentations/flow-control-with-promises/#/

and here is a list of other Promise/A spec implementations:

**JQuery**

- http://api.jquery.com/promise The #1 choice in jQuery-land

**Promises/A+**

- http://github.com/kriskowal/ The #1 choice in Node-land
- http://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js The most lightweight choice
- http://github.com/cujojs/when The speediest choice
- http://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md

Answer (score 0):

I use [nimble](http://caolan.github.io/nimble/) for that. I would create a list of check functions. Every check function checks certain storage (check can be synchronous or asynchronous) and only continues with the next function if a value wasn't found. Otherwise functions executes the given callback and proceed to the next step.

```
var flow = require('nimble');

flow.series([
  function checkInMemcache(callback) {
    // get memResult
    if (memResult) { // result found
      onResult(result);
    } else { // continue with the next step
      callback();
    }
  },
  function checkInMongo(callback) {
    // check in MongoDB, like
    mongo.asyncCheck(function(result) {
      if (result) { // result found
        onResult(result);
      } else { // continue with the next step
        callback();
      }
    });
  },
  function checkOther(callback) {
    // perform other checks
  }
]);

function onResult(result) {
  // do something
}
```

Advantage of such control flows is that it avoids callback nesting. It is also possible to implement similar control flow without any modules by creating an array of check-functions and implementing a `next()` method, which `shift()` next functions from the array and executes it. If that functions has a result, it executes `onResult()`. Otherwise it calls `next()` again and so on until array becomes empty.

Nimble module is very small and it allows to execute serial, parallel and mixed flows in such manner.